# Ensure thread running independently of tkinter mainloop doesn't access an element which no longer exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

I'm creating a tkinter application and I want to disable certain GUI elements while a particular set of threads are running. Basically one button starts up all the threads and they get added to a list which is a member of a class named `Form`. I have a separate thread which is a class member and is constantly checking the list of threads to see if it is empty; as long as there is at least one living thread in the list, the GUI elements should be disabled.

```
class Form()
  def __init__(self):
    ...
    self.check_running_threads_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.check_running_threads)
    self.check_running_threads_thread.start()
```

The issue is that I need this thread to quit running on application exit. The way I have been handling that is like so in main:

```
root = tk.Tk()
myForm = Form(root)
root.mainloop()
myForm.kill_threads = True
```

and the thread function that is started on the call of `__init()__` of the `Form` class is:

```
  def check_running_threads(self):
    while not self.kill_threads:
      for key, val in self.items.items():
        if len(self.running_threads) > 0:
          if key.endswith("entry"):
            val.config(state='readonly')
          elif key.endswith('button'):
            val['state'] = tk.DISABLED
        else:
          if key.endswith("entry"):
            val.config(state='normal')
          elif key.endswith('button'):
            val['state'] = tk.NORMAL
      self.running_threads = [th for th in self.running_threads if th.is_alive()]
      time.sleep(0.1)
```

where `self.items` is just a dictionary containing all the tk gui elements, indexed by a unique name.

The problem is that sometimes when the mainloop ends, such as by me exiting out of the application, the `check_running_threads()` function could be anywhere in the loop before `kill_threads` gets set to `True`, meaning it could try to change the state of the tk gui elements  when they no longer exist. This leads to the program freezing and never exiting. The tk window is destroyed, but the command line window hangs forever.

What is the proper way to handle this? How can I ensure a thread running independently of the tkinter mainloop doesn't access an element which no longer exists?

2022-09-05 Edit:

Here is a complete minimal example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
import time
import random

class Form():
  def __init__(self, root):
    self.kill_threads = False
    self.running_threads = []
    self.items = {}
    
    self.btn = ttk.Button(root, text='Press me, wait for num threads to be zero, then click "X" button', command=self.run_threads)
    self.btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    
    self.items['my_button'] = self.btn
    
    for jj in range(60):
      new = ttk.Button(root, text='', width=0)
      self.items[f'my_{jj}_button'] = new
      new.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    
    self.check_running_threads_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.check_running_threads)
    self.check_running_threads_thread.start()
  
  def thread_func(self):
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 2.5))
   
  def run_threads(self):
    for ii in range(30):
      mythread = threading.Thread(target = self.thread_func)
      mythread.start()
      self.running_threads.append(mythread)

  def check_running_threads(self):
    while not self.kill_threads:
      for key, val in self.items.items():
        if key.endswith("button"):
          if len(self.running_threads) > 0:
            val['state'] = tk.DISABLED
          else:
            val['state'] = tk.NORMAL
      print("Num threads running:", len(self.running_threads))
      self.running_threads = [th for th in self.running_threads if th.is_alive()]
      time.sleep(0.2)

root = tk.Tk()
myForm = Form(root)
root.mainloop()
myForm.kill_threads = True
```

All the excess buttons are there to represent other GUI elements that are in my actual program. The more there are, the more likely it seems the program hangs on exit.

Here's a video of me running it. You can see the behavior is sometimes inconsistent (it doesn't always hang, such as the third time I ran it):

https://youtu.be/JhKxRYVujQg

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new method in your Form class that will be called on close:

```
root = tk.Tk()
myForm = Form(root)
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", myForm.wait_till_threads_killed)
root.mainloop()
```

Where you method would look something like this:

```
def wait_till_threads_killed(self):
    self.kill_threads = True
    self.check_running_threads_thread.join()
    for t in self.running_threads:
        t.join()
    self.parent.destroy()
```

After having added root as parent in the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, root):
    self.parent = root
```

Edit: adding `destroy()` otherwise the window won't close + waiting for all threads

Edit2: note that this is only needed if you want to *wait for the threads to finish*. If want to kill them on exit, just set them as daemons in your initial code (then you don't necessarily need `protocol`):

```
mythread = threading.Thread(target = self.thread_func, daemon=True)
```

Comment: Sadly, this didn't solve it. Once again, I think my `check_running_threads` function still ends up accessing a deleted element. It is still freezing, but this time the tk window doesn't get destroyed. I don't have the issue in either case if I remove all of the `.config()` function calls.

Comment: Ignore my first comment, it was incorrect. I wanted to edit it to say: Sadly, this didn't solve it. Even if I remove the `.config()` function calls, both command line and the window freeze. In my original code, if I removed the `config()` function calls from the thread function, it actually exited properly.

Comment: Have you tried to debug to see where it freezes? Hard to help you further without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have updated my post with a complete minimal reproducible example. See if you have the same issue on your machine. Make sure you run it a few times because the behavior isn't always consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the example! It seems that it crashes only when you exit before all threads are done. I edited my answer in order to wait for all threads (also I forgot to destroy the window in the new method => fixed that too). Let me know if it works!

Comment: Unfortunately incorporating your new solution still froze the window. See here: https://pastebin.com/raw/FegUSNsT. However, I was able to get it to work by setting the `check_running_threads_thread` to be a daemon, rather than all of the other threads. In other words, the **only** change I had to make to fix it was `self.check_running_threads_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.check_running_threads, daemon = True)`, rather than anything else you suggested. I am not completely sure of the implications of this, however.

Comment: Simply setting the `check_running_threads_thread` to a daemon seems to solve the issue, but I'm wondering if that's really the proper way to handle it.

Comment: Funny, I can't get it to freeze with the code from pastebin. If you only set `check_running_threads_thread` as daemon, you might still have problems when you try to exit before it gets to 0. If you don't care that's a perfectly fine solution.